# Haskell Stack + Cabal ignore 'main-is' option and fail to build app

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

**Q: How to adjust cabal(stack?) settings so that `app/LogAnalysis.hs` is treated as main log after all?**

Here is how I got myself this error:

- Created new project with `stack new xyz`
- Renamed `app/Main.hs` to `app/LogAnalysis.hs`
- Adjusted `main-is` option in `xyz.cabal` file

Problem is I either entered that data somehow incorrectly or cabal ignores that new value. Here is error I get:

```
Preprocessing executable 'WeekTwo-exe' for WeekTwo-0.1.0.0...

<no location info>: error:
    output was redirected with -o, but no output will be generated
because there is no Main module.
```

Here is relevant entry in `xyz.cabal`

```
executable WeekTwo-exe
    hs-source-dirs:      app
    main-is:             LogAnalysis.hs
    ghc-options:         -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
    build-depends:       base
                       , WeekTwo
    default-language:    Haskell2010
```

And module in question is:

```
module LogAnalysis where
import Log

main :: IO ()
main = print (parseMessage "I 29 la la")
```

*Versions:
Stack - Version 1.3.2
GHC - 7.15
Cabal - 1.24.0.0*

PS if it's of any interest I'm doin 2nd week of Haskel course CIS 194.

Comment: GHC requires that the module that requires the main `main :: IO ()` is named `Main`. Modules must generally have a filepath that corresponds to the module name. You'll have to rename `LogAnalysis.hs` to `Main.hs` again.

Comment: Isn't `main-is` supposed to override this?

Comment: I think `main-is` serves only to point at the right `Main` module when there are several.

Comment: The project worked for me when I did your created/renamed/adjusted....  Then `stack exec xyz-exe` works for me, printing "somefunc".  What command are you running when you get the error?

Comment: stack build - look at accepted answer. I mistaken meaning of `main-is`, and thought it will make ghc look into different **module**, while in truth it only tells ghc to look for module `Main` inside different file then `Main.hs`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible you changed `module Main where` to `module LogAnalysis where`?  If you did, you would get exactly this error.

`Main-is` just says check for the `Main` module inside this file, but it must still be the `Main` module, not the `LogAnalysis` module.  This makes it clear that the main function in this file should be run, rather than some main functions that might happen to exist in some other modules.

Comment: You [don't need to rename the module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46895256). You just need to tell GHC the name of your main module. You can do this in your cabal file with: 

`ghc-options: -main-is LogAnalysis`