# can't define multiple executables

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have two files in `app` folder

```
app/
|-- Main.hs
|-- SomeFunc2.hs
```

The `SomeFunc2.hs` is just to print a different string

```
module SomeFunc2 where

import Lib

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "someFunc2"
```

When I define multiple executables in `package.yaml` like this

```
executables:
  multiexes-exe:
    main:                Main.hs
    source-dirs:         app
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    dependencies:
    - multiexes

  somefunc2-exe:
    main:                SomeFunc2.hs
    source-dirs:         app
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    dependencies:
    - multiexes
```

I got error:

```
▸ stack build
Building all executables for `multiexes' once. After a successful build of all of them, only specified executables will be rebuilt.
multiexes-0.1.0.0: configure (lib + exe)
Configuring multiexes-0.1.0.0...
multiexes-0.1.0.0: build (lib + exe)
Preprocessing library for multiexes-0.1.0.0..
Building library for multiexes-0.1.0.0..
[2 of 2] Compiling Lib              ( src/Lib.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Lib.o )
Preprocessing executable 'multiexes-exe' for multiexes-0.1.0.0..
Building executable 'multiexes-exe' for multiexes-0.1.0.0..
[1 of 3] Compiling Main             ( app/Main.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/multiexes-exe/multiexes-exe-tmp/Main.o ) [Lib changed]
[3 of 3] Compiling SomeFunc2        ( app/SomeFunc2.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/multiexes-exe/multiexes-exe-tmp/SomeFunc2.o )
Linking .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/multiexes-exe/multiexes-exe ...
Preprocessing executable 'somefunc2-exe' for multiexes-0.1.0.0..
Building executable 'somefunc2-exe' for multiexes-0.1.0.0..
Warning: Enabling workaround for Main module 'Main' listed in 'other-modules'
illegaly!
[1 of 2] Compiling Paths_multiexes  ( .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/somefunc2-exe/autogen/Paths_multiexes.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/somefunc2-exe/somefunc2-exe-tmp/Paths_multiexes.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling SomeFunc2        ( app/SomeFunc2.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/somefunc2-exe/somefunc2-exe-tmp/SomeFunc2.o )

<no location info>: error:
    output was redirected with -o, but no output will be generated
because there is no Main module.


--  While building custom Setup.hs for package multiexes-0.1.0.0 using:
      /Users/leo/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.0.1.0_ghc-8.2.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.0.1.0 build lib:multiexes exe:multiexes-exe exe:somefunc2-exe --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file -fdiagnostics-color=always"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

How to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: It seems your executables are both called `multiexes-exe`. I suspect that is causing problems.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. I updated, but is still causing the same problem

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/50659327/1100107

Answer (score 7):

Found a solution, if I create a folder for each executable and have a `Main.hs` in each folder, then it works.

```
app/
|-- Main.hs
somefunc2/
|-- Main.hs
```

In package.yaml, change the source-dirs to be those folders:

```
executables:
  multiexes-exe:
    main:                Main.hs
    source-dirs:         app
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    dependencies:
    - multiexes

  somefunc2-exe:
    main:                Main.hs
    source-dirs:         somefunc2
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    dependencies:
    - multiexes
```

Answer (score 1):

The module that contains the main function and is supposed to become an executable must be named `Main`, as in

```
module Main (main) where
```

You can also omit the module declaration altogether to the same effect. Your problem is in

```
module SomeFunc2 where
```

This convention is specified in [the Haskell report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#x11-980005), and while GHC [allows to change the module name](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/phases.html#ghc-flag--main-is%20%E2%9F%A8thing%E2%9F%A9) containing `main`, Cabal [does not](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/pull/5122/files).

To quote from the last link:

> Further, while the name of the file may
>      vary, the module itself must be named `Main`.

So in this case it's fine to name the module `Main` (or omit the module name declaration) even though the file itself is not called `Main.hs`.

Comment: Then the answer is impossible? I can't rename `SomeFunc2` to `Main`, because there is `Main.hs` exist already. 
But if I can't define multiple executables in `packages.yaml`, then it doesn't make sense that the section is called executable`s`, which sounds as if it supported multiple executables.

Comment: It is possible; I updated the answer to make it more clear. Also, if you really want to name both files `Main.hs`, you could place them in different directories (different `source-dirs`).

Comment: No. It doesn't work. If I change the `SomeFunc2.hs` to be `module Main where`, I get the following error: 

    File name does not match module name:
    Saw: ‘Main’
    Expected: ‘SomeFunc2’
  |
1 | module Main where