# hspec defined tests invoked with stack throw an error when test file is defined as a module

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, hspec

I'm trying to get my head around the reason why the test file containing unit-tests which is defined as a module fails when run with `stack build --test`.

Say having a simple test module defined from scratch with:

```sh
stack new test-module
cd test-module

vim package.yaml # remove "executables" section, add "hspec" as tests dependency
```

Following "[getting started](https://hspec.github.io/getting-started.html)" instructions from Hspec documentation I've modified files such as:

#### Step 1: Describe your desired behavior

```hs
-- file test/Spec.hs

module LibSpec where

import Test.Hspec
import Lib

main :: IO ()
main = hspec $ do
    describe "divides" $ do
        it "returns True when the first number divides the second" $
           2 `divides` 4 `shouldBe` True
```

#### Step 2: Write some code

```hs
-- file src/Lib.hs

module Lib (divides) where

divides :: Integer -> Integer -> Bool
divides d n = rem n d == 0
```

Running `stack build --test` throws the following error:

```
<no location info>: error:
    output was redirected with -o, but no output will be generated
because there is no Main module.
```

When I comment out the "module definition" line from the `test/Spec.hs` file the build succeeds and the unit-test passes:

```hs
-- file test/Spec.hs

-- Notice the next line is commented out:
-- module LibSpec where

import Test.Hspec
import Lib

main :: IO ()
main = hspec $ do
    describe "divides" $ do
        it "returns True when the first number divides the second" $
           2 `divides` 4 `shouldBe` True
```

Is that Hspec related or Stack related? Or maybe am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's part of Haskell the language.

> A Haskell program is a collection of modules, one of which, by convention, must be called `Main` and must export the value `main`.
>
> An abbreviated form of module, consisting only of the module body, is permitted. If this is used, the header is assumed to be `module Main(main) where`.
>
> ---
>
> The Haskell 2010 report, section 5 (Modules) https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#x11-980005

---

See also the cabal documentation, about the configuration that `package.yaml` is a proxy for, the field containing the test/executable file:

> `main-is`: (...)  while the name of the file may vary, the module itself must be named Main.
>
> ---
>
> https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#pkg-field-executable-main-is

---

GHC has an option `-main-is MyModule.mymain` to override this behavior ([documented in the GHC user guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/phases.html#ghc-flag--main-is%20%E2%9F%A8thing%E2%9F%A9)).

Comment: I just double-checked - when instead of running `stack build --test` I put `src/Lib.hs` file and `test/Spec.hs` file in the top directory and following the Hspec tutorial I invoke `stack exec -- runhaskell Spec.hs` WITH the module definition (uncommented) it doesn't throw an error. Now it's even more confusing : P

Comment: That IS very confusing.

Comment: Is that possible that `runhaskell` (which as far as I understand is an alias of `runghc` and is a way to run Haskell programs without compiling them) extracts whatever the module is called and somehow overwrites the `main-is` option with it?

Comment: Yes definitely.