# GHC compiles to .o and .hi but no executable

Tags: haskell, ghc

I've been working on a small file which I've been compiling and running as I go. My directory contains `Log.hs` and `LogAnalysis.hs`.

`LogAnalysis.hs` looks like this:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}
module LogAnalysis where

import Log

parseMessage :: String -> LogMessage
--some code...

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn (show (parseMessage ("Some log message text")))
```

When I compile the `LogAnalysis.hs` with GHC I was getting an executable, along with some other binary files:

```
$ ll
Log.hi
Log.hs
Log.o
LogAnalysis     <-- this is the executable which has disappeared
LogAnalysis.hi
LogAnalysis.hs
LogAnalysis.o
```

I made some small changes and now when I run `ghc LogAnalysis.hs` I get only the `.hi` and `.o` files but no executable. The output is:

```
[1 of 2] Compiling Log              ( Log.hs, Log.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling LogAnalysis      ( LogAnalysis.hs, LogAnalysis.o )
```

I'm not even sure what I changed, but it wasn't anything major. Any idea what could be triggering this? Is there some way to force GHC to produce an executable?

Specs: GHC 8.8.3, macOS 10.15.5

Comment: But there is an executable?

Comment: Please include the command line you're using. Also, what is the name of the `LogAnalysis.hs` module?

Comment: Old version of GHC requires a `—make` switch: `ghc —make LogAnalysis.hs`. In newer versions this became automatic if the provided file is a `Main` module. Since the default module header name the module as `Main`, I suspect your changes include adding a module header, and naming the module as something other than `Main`.

Comment: Amazing detective work @Krantz. thank you, that was it! Solution was, since my file began `module LogAnalysis where
import Log`, to compile with `ghc -main-is LogAnalysis LogAnalysis.hs`

Comment: @JoshFriedlander, you should add that as an answer.

Comment: @dfeuer OK, done. Thanks for your help! Also, I'd be grateful if you could let me know if my explanation of the problem was accurate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since I was declaring the file as a module not named `Main`, GHC by default doesn't create an executable. In order to compile this module into an executable, we can use GHC's `main-is` flag. (Thanks to [Krantz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8578679/krantz) in the comments and Willem Van Onsem's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46895256/6220759) for this.) So compiling with

```
ghc -main-is LogAnalysis LogAnalysis.hs
```

gives the output

```
[2 of 2] Compiling LogAnalysis      ( LogAnalysis.hs, LogAnalysis.o )
Linking LogAnalysis ...
```

So GHC has linked the executable `LogAnalysis` which is the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to fix it, delete the second line:

```
module LogAnalysis where
```

I believe that when you define it as a module, ghc understands that it is just a module that will be imported in another file so it doesn't create an executable.